# How to create Influxdb alert for deviating from average hourly values?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

So I'm trying to find any documentation on more complex Flux queries but after days of searching I'm still lost. I want to be able to calculate average values for each hour of the week and then when new data comes in I want to check if it deviates by x standard deviations for that hour.

Basically I want to have 24x7 array fields each representing the mean/median value for each hour of the week for the last 1 year. Then I want to compare last days values for each hour against these averages and report an error. I do not understand how to calculate these averages. Is there some hidden extensive documentation on Flux?

I don't really need a full solution, just some direction would be nice. Like, are there some utility functions for this in the standard lib or whatever

EDIT: After some reading, it really looks like all I need to do is use the window and aggregateWindow functions but I haven't yet found how exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, this is what worked for me. Needs some cleaning up but gets the values successfully grouped per hour+weekday and the mean of all the values

```
import "date"
tab1 = from(bucket: "qweqwe")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "asdasd")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "reach")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)


mapped = tab1 
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with wd: string(v: date.weekDay(t: r._time)), h: string(v: date.hour(t: r._time)) }))
  |> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with mapped_time: r.wd + " " + r.h }))

grouped = mapped
  |> group(columns: ["mapped_time"], mode: "by")
  |> mean()
  |> group() 
  |> toInt()

  |> yield()
```